# what does "landslides, & landmines" mean here?

Tags: meaning

Fixing, to find you
In this treacherous terrain
There's l**landslides, landmines**
It's a jungle that we made
You're not the king of it no more

Does it denote " our mistakes and shortfalls" ?

Comment: In this particular example, it is used as a metaphor, yes, but in another context it could just as well be meant literally.

Comment: By the way, "landmines" sounds like something a lot worse than just mistakes or shortfalls.

Comment: then like what please? I'm translating, so I need to have some synonyms so close to what it implies.

Comment: what about this part;  [ 
No matter how long it'll hurt like this
When I go into the apocalypse
I'm gonna go crazy
Crazy
To lose you].   ( here go into the apocalypse), does it mean sth that is revealed to the speaker or no, it means literally go into the end time? then end time of what? the world? or their search or relationship?

Comment: I'm not sure. I didn't know the song, so I had to google it - that's why I didn't want to post an answer; not familiar enough with the subject. Anyway, the song is called "Apocalypse" and it's about a relationship blowing up. Lines like "I break out my artillery" sound like more than just people recognising their own faults. They're actively fighting!

Comment: Waitaminute. If you are translating this into another language, why not translate "landmines" literally?

Comment: because if "landmines" and "landslides' both together means our mistakes, misbehavior, and so on, then it should not be translated literally. it should be  translated the meaning these words try to express and convey.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the song's name. BTW. I'm not in a hurry, take your time. And, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Is there any website which people discuss the meaning of the lyrics?

Answer (score 1):

It's metaphoric and implies "**obstacles**" and "**difficulties**".

Comment: Thanks Sina, and this is what I already landed on, but yours secured the answer. Good Job.

Comment: No worries... Cheers mate!